# PHP ODBC sql-server - moving to another server

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

On my old server I have everything configured for PHP to be able to connect to MSSQL through odbc. I use this simple function to connect to database:

```
$connid = odbc_connect('ww', 'sa', ODBC_PS);
```

It works but on the new server it doesn't connect. Can you suggest what does this strange connection string `'ww'` means? I use SQL server 2012 now, before I had 2008.

Error I get when trying to connect is:

Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in(..)

Comment: "WW" here is the database source name for the connection. Have a look at http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php.

Comment: Yeah, I already found it :) I've set the source basing on the configuration from my old server and it works, thanks